# Mensaje no sale en la barra de tareas java

Tags: java, timer

Mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para que me salga un msj en la barra de tarea llamando a mi método **MensajeTrayIcon()** desde otra clase? Es decir, lo llamo pero no me realiza ninguna acción, el msj no aparece en mi barra de tareas, tengo un Timer que se dispara cada X segundos, el msj debería chequear si existe algo para mostrar que aparezca en la barra de notificaciones sino que no haga nada.

Tengo mi metodo **MensajeTrayIcon** que se encuentra en mi clase notificacion.

```
    public class Notificacion {

    private JFrame parent;
    private PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
    private final Image image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("notificaciones.png")).getImage();
    private final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "Notificacion.png", popup);
    //para el Timer
    private Timer timer;
    ///////////////////////////
    SystemTray systemTray;

    public Notificacion() {
    }

    public void instanciarTray() {
        trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);
        systemTray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
    }

    public void segundoPlano() {
        try {
            if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
                systemTray.add(trayIcon);

                //Se inicia una tarea cuando se minimiza           
                if (timer != null) {
                    timer.cancel();
                }
                timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new miTimerTask(), 2000, 5000);//Se ejecuta cada 5 segundos
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR);
        }
    }

//    Muestra una burbuja con la accion que se realiza
    public void MensajeTrayIcon(String texto, MessageType tipo) {
        trayIcon.displayMessage("Advertencia.", texto, tipo);
        System.out.println("pasa por aqui");
    }
}
```

Dicho metodo es llamado desde otra clase la cual hace una serie de cosas el cual compara si encuentra coincidencias entre el contenido de un Map y un arraylist deberia mostrar un msj en la barra de notificaciones en el caso que ahiga algo para mostrar pero no lo hace.

```
    public class LeerArchivos {

    Notificacion notificacion = new Notificacion();
    ArrayList<String> keyArray = new ArrayList<>();

    public void leer(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {
        Map<String, String> mapaCodigosArchivo = new HashMap();

        try {
            // Abrimos el archivo con la ruta especificada.
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(new File("Sucursales.txt"));
            // Creamos el objeto de entrada
            DataInputStream entrada = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            // Creamos el Buffer de Lectura
            BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entrada));
            String contenido;
            // Leer el archivo linea por linea
            while ((contenido = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] separador = contenido.split(",");
                mapaCodigosArchivo.put(separador[0], separador[1]);
            }
            keyArray.clear();
            //Recorremos el arrayList
            for (String nombreArchivo : arrayList) {
                String[] separador = nombreArchivo.split("_");
                String codSucursal = separador[0].replace("PDA", "").trim();
                keyArray.add(codSucursal);
            }
            for (String key : mapaCodigosArchivo.keySet()) {
                int encontrados = this.contarTicketPorSucursal(keyArray, key);
                if (encontrados > 0) {
                    notificacion.MensajeTrayIcon("Tienes " + encontrados + " ticket pendiente de la sucursal: " + mapaCodigosArchivo.get(key), MessageType.INFO);
//                    System.out.println("Tienes " + encontrados + " ticket pendiente de la sucursal: " + mapaCodigosArchivo.get(key));
                }
            }
            // Cerramos el archivo
            entrada.close();
        } catch (Exception e) { //Catch de excepciones
            System.err.println("Ocurrio un error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private int contarTicketPorSucursal(ArrayList<String> keyArray, String key) {
        int contador = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < keyArray.size(); i++) {
            if (keyArray.get(i).equals(key)) {
                contador++;
            }
        }
        return contador;
    }
}
```

Si debugeo el método **MensajeTrayIcon** imprimiendo por pantalla lo llama, pasa por ahí el cod pero no sale en la barra de tareas me explico? Como podría hacer para que me salga dicho msj..

Desde ya gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Por lo tanto`displayMessage` parece no hacer lo que quieres... ¿por qué no pones el código de lo que no funciona en lugar del que sabes que sí se ejecuta?

Comment: Si no entendí mal, quieres que la notificación esa, te salga como si fuera un modal (de cara a la barra de tareas) ?

Comment: @MaQuiNa1995 Claro exactamente! Quiero que si existen elementos para mostrar, en este caso ticket pendientes de facturación, el sistema lo evalué y me lance el msj en la barra de notificaciones si existe algo para mostrar, me explico? Primero quiero lograr que muestre el msj, después lo otro

Comment: @Pablo Lozano E modificado mi pregunta agregándole mas código así es mas entendible y me puedan ayudar con lo que necesito. Desde ya gracias